# Footer moving to the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, header, footer

so the problem is that my footer (which should be sitting at the bottom of the page) is moving to the top of the page just beneath my fixed header.

here is my code:

```
    <head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Roboto:400,100,300,100italic,300italic:latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>



</head>
<style>





h1 { 

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 100; font-size: 56px; line-height: 56px; color: #555; letter-spacing: -2px;  
  }


  h2 { 

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.3em; color: #5b6064; letter-spacing: -1px;
  }

p { 

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.8em; color: #5b6064; margin-bottom: 18px;
  }

a { 

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 1.1875rem; 
  }


.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed; left: 0%; 
    top:0px;



}
.header {
    height:60px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #e0e0e0;
    width:100%;



}


  .logo{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #e0e0e0;
    background-image: url('hjhjhjk');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;

  }

  .nav{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #e0e0e0;

  }

  .login{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #e0e0e0;
    text-align: center;


  }

  .kob{
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 59px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #0099cc;
    background-color: #00b6e7;
    text-align: center;

  }


a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #787a78;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

  .container{
    max-width: 900px;

    margin: 0px auto; 
  }


  .bullet{
    margin: 60px auto;
    max-width: 900px; 
  }
  .leftimgbullet{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url('asdasd);

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-position: center center;

  }

  .righttxtbullet{
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;

    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;

  }

   .kob1{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 59px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #0099cc;
    background-color: #00b6e7;
    text-align: center;

  }

.footer{
background-color: #f6f6f6;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;

}



</style>


<div class="header-cont">

  <div class="header"><div class="logo"></div>



    <div class="kob"><div style="margin-top: 18px;"><a style="color: #ffffff;" href="asdasdasd">asdasdasd</a></div></div></div>

</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="bullet">
<div class="leftimgbullet"></div>
    <div class="righttxtbullet"><h1 style="margin-bottom: 24px;">why is the headline on top of the footer?</h1>
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 18px;">what is this?</h2>
      <p>asdasdasdasd</p>
      <div class="kob1"><div style="margin-top: 18px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;"><a style="color: #ffffff;" href="sss.dk">crazt</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

 <div class="footer"></div>


<script>

  $(function() {

    var $sidebar = $(".header-cont"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 0;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                top: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });

});?

</script>
```

i have no clue why the footer is sticking to the top, maybe it's my div setup? i have no clue, i've tried everything i know. please help me, all help appreciated.
all help appreciated! Thank you! heres a code pen:

```
http://codepen.io/jaxi123/pen/ydBHz
```

Comment: Would `<body>` tags help?

Answer (score 0):

because you're not clearing your floated elements. Either use a clearfix or set `overflow:hidden` on `.bullet` (the parent)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qbn7r5uc/1/)